# Where in Azure portal can I get the server time?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service

The most likely reason for a bug we are seeing seems to be a disparity between the time on our azure database and web-app-service.

In the old days when I could just hop onto a remote desktop, I know how to check what these are.  How can I tell nowadays?

Looking at the activity log and using GETDATE(), there appears to be a discrepency for daylight saving (BST).  How do I go about changing this?  (Assuming I confirm it is the case with the answer to the forst question here)

Answer (score 3):

SQL Azure database always use UTC time.For that reason you should not use datetime data type. Instead you should use datetimeoffset.

You should also capture the system date using sysdatetimeoffset() instead of using getdate().

When you retrieve dates from the database tables you should then use “AT TIME ZONE” as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/at-time-zone-transact-sql).

Answer (score 1):

All the Azure SQL Databases use UTC for their date and time. You should get the same value for GETDATE or GETUTCDATE. That would explain the BST discrepancy.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have mentioned about Azure App Service WebApp time zone as well, I would like to highlight that in an Azure WebApp by default, the time zone is always UTC, but you can change it.

You can also find the list in your registry 
under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WindowsNT\CurrentVersion\Time Zones. If the string is not recognized, it falls back to UTC.

The best way to test that it works is to type time from [Kudu console](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2014/03/24/using-kudu-with-windows-azure-web-sites/).

Examples:

WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE=Eastern Standard Time
WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE=AUS Eastern Standard Time

You could add an application setting via the Azure Portal named “WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE” equal to the name of the time zone in question (basically the same string as the key name at HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows Nt\CurrentVersion\Time Zones).

Refer the [GitHub link](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Configurable-settings#set-the-time-zone) which talks about this specific setting for more details.